# Errors for Latex in Rstudio

Tags: pdf, compilation, latex, rstudio

*edit) This is wierd, and has happened to me before.
I'll make the document in some other editor such as TeXshop, and it'll compile. Then i'll copy and paste the code into RStudio, hit compile, and it'll work, but wouldn't work prior to compiling it in TeXshop.
I'll throw up the log file next time this occurs

I'm trying to switch to LaTex, but the jargon and technical details make this seem overbearing.

While using Rstudio, and editing a .tex document,I can't seem to "compile pdf" for the sake of me.

"Running texi2dvi...
Error in tools:::texi2dvi(file = fileName, pdf = TRUE, index = index) : 
  Running 'texi2dvi' on 'lab5real.tex' failed.
Messages:
/usr/bin/texi2dvi: pdflatex exited with bad status, quitting.
/usr/bin/texi2dvi: see lab5real.log for errors.
"

Comment: For completeness, add `lab5real.log` to your post by editing it. That way everyone can see whether the problem lies with Rstudio, or perhaps with your LaTeX code.

Comment: will do, thanks. I believe it's Rstudio. If I run the .tex file in another editor say TeXShop, it'll compile

Comment: Could it be that after running the code through Texshop you already have intermediate Latex output files like *.out, enabling a not correctly configured RStudio to yield a pdf, while when you start with a clean compilation it cannot?